# How many requests on server does Collection.find()?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am a rookie in Meteor, so I hope I´am not asking something stupid.

My concern is: Will Meteor always do a request on the server when I´ll call the Collection.find() method? Or it fetch the data to the client by subscribing to them, and every find() get the data only from client?

I have a complex document and I need a couple helpers to render it. I want to use the advantage of Meteors reactive behavior, to render the changes that user makes to the document. I don´t want to pass the collection into session and reactive variables are not really an option because I´m using a couple subtemplates.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `find` will not trigger communication with the server.

According to the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection) for `new Mongo.Collection`:

> On the client (and on the server if you specify a connection), a Minimongo instance is created. Minimongo is essentially an in-memory, non-persistent implementation of Mongo in pure JavaScript. It serves as a local cache that stores just the subset of the database that this client is working with. **Queries (find) on these collections are served directly out of this cache, without talking to the server.**